# Changing title on a subplot of Lmplot

Tags: seaborn

```
lm = sns.lmplot(x='early_mean_zscores', y='late_mean_zscores', col='cat', data=combo)
fig = lm.fig
fig.suptitle("Improvement from Early to Late assignments")
a1 = fig.axes[1]
a1.title("adsadas")
```

I would like to set the title of the subplots generated by hand, i.e. not based on the col='cat'. This code, and many permutations of it that I have tried don't seem to work.

I don't understand the timing of when the plot is fixed and displayed. Is it on the first line, lm = ... in which case it's not surprising that I cannot, retroactively change the title.

I could use some help on both fixing the code, and a clarification on the sequencing and theory of what is going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command to set a title is `ax.set_title()`. Using that, the code should work as expected.

A minimal example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

lm = sns.lmplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", col="smoker", data=tips)
fig = lm.fig
fig.suptitle("Custom Super Title")
a1 = fig.axes[1]
a1.set_title("Custom Title")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I wanted to try and experiment with settings in ipython. For example by calling a1.set_title("XXXX") but then plt.show() would not redisplay the graph. I would have to do the same whole sequence again. How come?

Comment: Not entirely sure. If not in interactive mode (plt.ion()) you can anyways not call `plt.show` more than once. If in interactive mode, you might call `fig.show()`. In any case this is probably a completely different question.

Answer (score 2):

depending on what you need, you could just use:

```
lm = sns.lmplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", col="smoker", data=tips).set_titles("{col_name}") # {col_name} is special parameter of actual column name
```